# «Прийти» или «придти»?

Tags: орфография, словоизменение

Как правильно писать: «при**йт**и» или «при**дт**и»?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Глагол «идти» (или устаревший «итти») — одно из самых древних слов русского языка. Раньше действительно употреблялась форма «при**дт**и» (с корнем *ид*, как в слове «пр**ид**ешь»), однако сейчас она исчезла из русского языка, заменившись формой «пр**ий**ти».

Таким образом, правильно — «пр**ий**ти».

Answer (score 20):

**Кодифицированным** написанием (по Розенталю) является «пр**ий**ти».

До некоторого времени несколько десятилетий обе формы употреблялись одновременно, в 19 веке и начале 20-го литературной формой была только «при**дт**и» («пр**ий**ти» относилась к просторечиям).

Comment: Во-первых, не к просторечиям, а к вполне себе классической литературной лексике. Во-вторых, до 60-х конкурировали прежде всего формы «при**тт**и» и «при**дт**и».

Comment: @behemothus «Какие ваши доказательства?» Я вот достаточно долго боролся с наследием классической русской литературы 19 века: «приДти» — а «приЙти» видел только в форме «прийтить» (в понятно каких источниках?).

Answer (score 8):

Современные нормы требуют формы "прийти", но "идти".
Ранее использовались еще и конкурирующие варианты "итти", "ийти", "притти" и "придти".

Повторю себя. И расскажу про интересный факт.
*Есть старый корректорский анекдот о том, как надо писать слово "идти": "Это смотря на каком этаже". В известном москвичам здании "Правды" размещалось несколько редакций (если не путаю, их там давно уже нет). Так вот, на разных этажах предлагалось три варианта. "Идти", "итти" и "ийти". Дело, правда, происходило до 56 г.*

Answer (score 1):

Глагол довольно древний. Образован от начальной формы *"итти"*. Возможно поэтому некоторые думают, что стоит сохранить старое написание и использовать *"при**тт**и"*.

Завершённое в 1956 году упорядочивание русской орфографии узаконило форму глагола *"пр**ий**ти"*, что и было сразу занесено в изданный в 1957 году орфографический словарь под редакцией Д.Н. Ушакова.

С того времени единственной правильной формой глагола является *"пр**ий**ти"* - без Д, но с Й.

Хорошей подсказкой для запоминания формы слова также может стать глагол с противоположным значением - антоним *"уйти"*.  Они имеют полностью одинаковый состав слова. Поменяем приставку -у- на -при- и получаем правильный орфографический вариант *"пр**ий**ти"*.

[Как правильно пишется «прийти»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/priyti)